how to add ckeditor 4.17 version vedio embed plugin in vue 2
I've been struggling for the past two days to successfully integrate the video embed plugin from CKEditor version 4.17 into my Vue 2 project. Despite meticulously following the instructions provided on the official CKEditor website at https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/videoembed, I've been unable to get it to work properly. It's been a frustrating experience, and I'm really in need of some assistance to resolve this issue. Any help or guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
